# Nuxt3 using Typescript gives Cannot find module '#imports' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've searched everywhere on why this is happening, with no results.

In a very basic component, doing this gives: **Cannot find module '#imports' or its corresponding type declarations**

```
import { setPageLayout } from '#imports';
```

The code works fine, but it has to do with types and not recognizing the imports with "#"

I did every config that is laid out in the Docs. Anyone have any ideas?

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxt/typescript-build",
      "@types/node"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json"
}
```

nuxt.config

```
import type { NuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/types';

const config: NuxtConfig = {
  buildModules: ['@nuxt/typescript-build'],
  vue: {
    config: {
      productionTip: false,
      devtools: true
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

vue-shim.d.ts

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

So Nuxt is not recognizing the "#imports" alias. To fix this, add the following to your tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "#imports": [".nuxt/imports.d.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

This fixed the issue immediately